# Testing a Tkinter Button object with an if statement

Tags: python, button, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a program that needs a GUI with buttons to do certain things, as is usually the case when having questions about Buttons, but I have ran into difficulties because while you can activate functions with buttons, you cannot test wether they are currently being pressed with an if statement. I know how to use check buttons and radio buttons, but I have not found anything else remotely useful. I need to be able to tell how long they are pressed, and to do things as they are being pressed that stop when they are released. I need a way of assigning a variable that will be true while you are still holding click down over the button, and false any other time, with a normal button, not one that toggles each time you press.

Comment: Check this: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you're having trouble with, so I took the liberty of coding up a little GUI that times how long a button is pressed.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

class ButtonTimer:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.master = root
        self.button = tk.Button(self.master, text="press me")  # Notice I haven't assigned the button a command - we're going to bind mouse events instead of using the built in command callback.
        self.button.bind('<ButtonPress>', self.press)       # call 'press' method when the button is pressed
        self.button.bind('<ButtonRelease>', self.release)   # call 'release' method when the button is released
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master)
        self.startTime = time.time()
        self.endTime = self.startTime

        self.button.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.label.grid(row=2, column=1)

    def press(self, *args):
        self.startTime = time.time()

    def release(self, *args):
        self.endTime = time.time()
        self.label.config(text="Time pressed: "+str(round(self.endTime - self.startTime, 2))+" seconds")

root = tk.Tk()
b = ButtonTimer(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Note:  I tested this in python 2.7 then changed the import from `Tkinter` to `tkinter`.  It will probably work in 3.x, but I haven't tested it with that version.

Comment: This helped a lot! Thnx! I didn't know the syntax of how to add separate commands for press and release, that was my problem, I thought there was a way of having a BooleanVer attached or something and I could use that, but this is much more helpful. I can also use this to attach a BooleanVar by making the functions turn it on and off respectively.Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that the rest of the program doesn't'to pause while the button is being held down?